# How do I get the location of linkable libraries in GHC?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm working on a project that produces a shared object (`.so`) file. The source code is in both C and Haskell. It needs to be linked with libraries for the GHC Runtime System and for the Hint Haskell module.

Currently, the command to compile the file is:

```
ghc -Weverything -Werror -fforce-recomp $^ -o $@ -dynamic -shared -lHSrts-ghc8.10.5 -lHShint-0.9.0.4-7GR8UnOuwIbHNCqCSHKCK0-ghc8.10.5
```

There must be a way to automate the finding of the libraries instead of hard-coding the names. I want the Makefile to continue to work with future releases of GHC and Hint. It seems to be that `ghc-pkg`
should be able to provide this, but I can't find how.

Comment: For anything more complicated than a hello-world, you would want to use higher-level build tools, such as `cabal` or `stack`, not `ghc` or `ghc-pkg`. Have you tried (researching) that?